# Link for populating today's date in a form

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I am using Java and JSF for creating a form and I need to click on a link which would say Today's date and clicking it will populate a form field with todays date.How should I code it out. I was planning to use JavaScript! Any help appreciated

Comment: depends on whether or not u wanna go to the server.... if u can afford going to the server use JSF (i wudnt do this) .. or else choose javascript....  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_date

Comment: The issue with going to the server, to me, is whether you want today's date based on the server's time zone, or based on the user's time zone.  Probably you want the user's date, so you want a pure javascript solution as @Kasturi linked to.

Comment: Ah, the users time zone. Well, server's time zone is covered in my answer, and client's in Kasturi's.

Comment: well I am kinda confused how to code that up using h:commandLink for the link that needs to be clicked. Also I am very new to Javascript!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id=Date name=Date value="">
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="JavaScript: document.getElementById('Date').value = new Date();">Today's Date</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a date picker that defaults to today's date. Try the [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but why would you want to collect todays date from user interface. I mean, it's not like the user will have to choose between different todays, right?

Why not just use `new Date()` in the method called by your action in Java layer.

Comment: I have a blank form field and users have to input date there, and usually that will be today's date, so it will be easier for the user's to click on a link that says todays date and populates the field as well instead of typing!!